# How does realloc() work?

Tags: c, realloc

Assuming that I have allocated memory using `malloc()`, if I do in my code:

```
char *newline = realloc ( oldline , newsize );
// Assuming oldline is the pointer to which the starting address
// of the memory which malloc() has returned, is assigned and,
// say, newsize is integer having 100 value.
```

Now my questions regarding it are:-

1. Is it necessary that `newline` will point to same address as `oldline`, which holds the previous initial address?
2. Is it so that in this case, `oldline` will be freed(implicitly) and `newline` will take the charge of memory addressing?
3. After the above code and after the work has been done, what should I do to free memory

   ```
   free(newline);
   ```

   or

   ```
   free(oldline);
   ```

   or both?

Comment: On a unix clone, open a terminal window and type `man realloc` and all your questions will be answered.  On other OS's you need to figure out where the documentation is.

Comment: Or have a look on the internet: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc

Comment: Required reading for any student of C: [C99 with Technical corrigenda TC1, TC2, and TC3 included](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)

Comment: @Deduplicator these are of C99?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depend if `realloc` was successful or not. If `realloc` is successful then:

1. No ! For example, if there is not enough contiguous memory after `oldline` then `newline` will be different from `oldline`.
2. Yes
3. `free(newline);` since `oldline` has been freed if necessary. After a realloc `oldline` should be considered as invalid pointer.

If it is not successful. Then, you use `oldline` as if nothing happened, in particular you should free it.

Comment: "After a *successful* realloc...". If realloc returns NULL, you do have to free oldline.

Comment: if realloc returns NULL _and size is not 0 and oldline is not 0_, you have to free oldline.

Comment: @Deduplicator: The standard guarantees that free(NULL) is a no-op. Furthermore, if you ask for 0 bytes and `realloc` (or `malloc` for that matter) returns a non-NULL value, you do have to `free` it. So the only valid test is "if oldline is not 0", but you don't have to test that because, as above, if oldline is 0, `free(oldline)` is harmless.

Comment: The question was _must free_, not _can free_. And i don't see where anything you said contradicts my comment.

Answer (score 1):

1) No.. in fact `newline` is not used at all (other than to store the results), why would you ask that?

2) Yes

3) Only the first.

Comment: for 1) `newline` may or may not points to same as of oldline.

Answer (score 1):

C standard for `realloc(old, size)`:

- size == 0

  - realloc might free old and return 0
  - alternatively realloc behaves as for size != 0 but cannot return 0
- size != 0

  - realloc might return 0. old is not touched
  - if the block pointed to by old is >= size, realloc might return old
  - alternatively realloc allocates a block >= size, copies all bytes from old up to size, frees old and returns this new block

You are responsible for whichever block persisted through this algorithm / was allocated.
Working those out:

1 No. Though it can be.

2 Yes, If size == 0 or returned != 0

3a free oldline, if returned 0 and size != 0

3b free newline, if returned != 0